# How to stop sibling components from Re-Rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of a component using another component like this:

```
const CompA = React.memo(({Vis})=>{
  console.log('Rendered CompA');
  return(<Pressable onPress={()=>{Vis[1](!Vis[0])}} style={...}></Pressable>);
})

const CompB = React.memo(({Vis})=>{
  console.log('Rendered CompB');
  return(<>{Vis[0]&&(<View style={...}></View>)}</>);
})

export default function App() {

  const Vis=useState(()=>true);

  return (<View style={styles.body}>
    <CompA Vis={Vis}/>
    <CompB Vis={Vis} />
  </View>);
}
```

but every time I toggle the visibility even `CompA` gets re rendered
How do I only re render `CompB` everytime I change the visibility?

Comment: This: `const Vis=useState(()=>true);` shouldn't be how you use `useState`. It has a very fixed syntax.

Comment: @Andy i mean it returns an array right? I just like to store it in a single variable so that I don't have to pass multiple props, nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: @cakelover - There is in this case, though: A) The array will never be `===` a previous array you got from `useState`, and B) You don't want to pass the flag to `CompA` because that changes every time you toggle the visibility of `CompB`. You could implement a custom comparison callback for `memo` to handle (A), but it would still have the issue of (B). There's also readability/semantics to consider.

Comment: 1) It makes your code less readable. 2) Ideally you should be [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) using a handler that you give to the child component, not passing down the setState function from your parent component to the child, particularly in such an opaque way. @cakelover

Comment: @Andy I understand now, also I didn't understand the lifting state up part it seems to be implemented using class components I'm fairly new and I've just worked with hooks, is there a hooks version or will I have to learn class components?

Comment: That is the hooks version. Instead of treating `useState` as an array think of it as two separate things: state, and the function that updates the state. @T.J.Crowder's answer shows best how to use them to make your code readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array you receive from `useState` will never be `===` a previous array you received from `useState`; React creates a new array when you call `useState` each time. Just like `[] === []` is always false, the check being done by `memo` on the props will always be false and it will re-render.

There are at least two ways to solve the problem:

1. Pass the component parts of that array instead, since the setter function is guaranteed to be stable, and only pass `CompA` the setter function since it doesn't need the flag (it can use the callback form of the setter).
2. If you really, really want to pass the array around instead, implement a custom `memo` callback for `CompA` that only looks at the second element in the array, and don't use the first element of the array in `CompA`. But I'd strongly recommend **not** doing that, the readability/semantics of it are very misleading/surprising.

Here's #1:

```
const CompA = React.memo(({setVisible}) => {
    console.log("Rendered CompA");
    return (<Pressable onPress={() => {setVisible(visible => !visible)}} style={...}></Pressable>);
});

const CompB = React.memo(({visible}) => {
    console.log("Rendered CompB");
    return (<>{visible && (<View style={...}></View>)}</>);
});

export default function App() {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true); // No need for the callback form here
  
    return (<View style={styles.body}>
        <CompA setVisible={setVisible} />
        <CompB visible={visible} />
    </View>);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const CompA = React.memo(({setVisible}) => {
    console.log("Rendered CompA");
    return (<button onClick={() => {setVisible(visible => !visible)}}>pressable</button>);
});

const CompB = React.memo(({visible}) => {
    console.log("Rendered CompB");
    // Unfortunately, the version of Babel used by Stack
    // Snippets is so old it doesn't understand shorthand
    // fragment syntax
    return (<React.Fragment>{visible && (<div>this is the View</div>)}</React.Fragment>);
});

function App() {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true); // No need for the callback form here
  
    return (<div>
        <CompA setVisible={setVisible} />
        <CompB visible={visible} />
    </div>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass particular props in components. `isVisible` and the function which change the value of `isVisible`. When passing `function` as p props to components and using `React.memo` you need to use `useCallback` in `function` hooks to prevent re-render stuff.

Read more about [memo and usecallback](https://dev.to/dinhhuyams/introduction-to-react-memo-usememo-and-usecallback-5ei3/)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const { useState, useCallback, memo } = React;

const CompA = memo(({ handleChange }) => {
  console.log("Rendered CompA");
  return <Pressable onPress={handleChange}>Comp A</Pressable>;
});

const CompB = memo(({ isVisible }) => {
  console.log("Rendered CompB", isVisible);
  return isVisible && <View> CompB</View>;
});

function App() {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    const handleChange = useCallback(() => setVisible((isVisible) => !isVisible),[]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <CompA handleChange={handleChange} />
      <CompB isVisible={isVisible} />
    </View>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Live Example**

```js
const { useState, useCallback, memo } = React;

const CompA = memo(({ handleChange }) => {
  console.log("Rendered CompA");
  return <button onClick={handleChange}>Comp A</button>;
});

const CompB = memo(({ isVisible }) => {
  console.log("Rendered CompB");
  return isVisible && <div> CompB</div>;
});

function App() {
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    () => setVisible((isVisible) => !isVisible),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <CompA handleChange={handleChange} />
      <CompB isVisible={isVisible} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution but it doesn't look pretty:

```
let UniVis;

const CompA = React.memo(({Vis})=>{
  console.log('Rendered CompA');
  return(<Pressable onPress={()=>{UniVis[1](!UniVis[0])}} style={...}></Pressable>);
});

const CompB = React.memo(({Vis})=>{
  console.log('Rendered CompB');
  return(<>{Vis[0]&&(<View style={...}></View>)}</>);
})

export default function App() {

  const Vis=useState(()=>true);
  UniVis=Vis;

  return (<View style={styles.body}>
    <CompA />
    <CompB Vis={Vis} />
  </View>);
}
```

but it does work